# Take Data from Multiple Sheets to One Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am a novice with VBA and am learning through a couple of books and this site. I do not have any code to display as it is beyond my skill level. I apologize for the inconvenience and thank you in advance for your assistance. ***Disclaimer; some of these steps are easy but it is specifically steps 2 and 6 that screw me up.***

**What it needs to do in written terms:**

***What you need to know:
"Agency", "COM", "HEN", "HTW" are sheets &
the new sheet will be called "Sept" after step 2***

1. Create a new sheet (That goes at the end of all other sheets)
2. New Sheet's Name = "Agency" Range A1 (This will
   be a month) (The new sheet will now be called "Sept" in the following steps)
3. "Sept" A1 = "Site"
4. "Sept" B1 = "Class"
5. "Sept" C1 = "Indicator"
6. "COM", "HEN", and "HTW"'s ranges A2:A20, B2:B20, and C2:20 get listed under the headers made in steps 3-5. Note, when helping me with the code, please do not group the ranges as A2:C20 as it will help more to keep them seperated to better fit my sheets later on.

Thank you!

Comment: "COM, HEN and HTWs ranges A2:A20, B2:B20 & C2:C20 get listed under the headers."So you mean that in the end you have 60 items under each header?

Comment: That is correct. This is also a small sample of the workbook. The actual workbook is much larger. I should've mentioned that.

Comment: Have you tried using For Each loops? Try building some code and see how far you get. Then show the community where you get stuck in writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Should do the trick.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DataCopy()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Agency")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COM")
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HEN")
Dim ws4 As Worksheet
Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HTW")

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = ws1.Range("A1").Value

Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws1.Range("A1").Value)
Dim cntr As Integer
cntr = 0
Dim ROffset As Integer
ROffset = 0

ws5.Range("A1").Value = "Site"
ws5.Range("B1").Value = "Class"
ws5.Range("C1").Value = "Indicator"

Dim GetSheet As Worksheet

Do Until cntr = 3
    If cntr = 0 Then
        Set GetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COM")
        ROffset = 0
    ElseIf cntr = 1 Then
        Set GetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HEN")
        ROffset = 19
    ElseIf cntr = 2 Then
        Set GetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HTW")
        ROffset = 38
    End If

    GetSheet.Range("A2:A20").Copy
    ws5.Range("A2:A20").Offset(ROffset, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    GetSheet.Range("B2:B20").Copy
    ws5.Range("B2:B20").Offset(ROffset, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    GetSheet.Range("C2:C20").Copy
    ws5.Range("C2:C20").Offset(ROffset, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    cntr = cntr + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Please note that is a pretty basic and static way to achieve the goal. If your ranges you want to get data from or paste to change, this code will not work/yield inaccurate results. However, it does get the job done for the question you asked.

Comment: This is perfect. This gives me a base to look into when updating such as named ranges and such. Thank you so much. I am also still looking into "For Each" as you mentioned above as that is a new code for me. It looks interesting for some of my other projects as well!

Comment: Glad to help. I recommend checking out Wise Owl VBA tutorials on Youtube to help you on your way. They helped me when I was getting started with VBA. Good luck!

Comment: I will look into it!